# Is it possible to have parameters that aren't used as arguments?

Tags: swift, parameters, arguments, optional-parameters

For example, I have `func test(paramA: String){}`.

Sometimes I want to pass a `string` as argument but other times, I definitely don't want to have an argument at all, but rather: `test()`

Is it possible to call both `test()` and `test("hello")` or does it need to be different functions?

Also I'm not sure if this is called something in particular. SO defined optional parameters as:

> An optional parameter is one that a caller can include in a call to a function or method, but doesn't have to. When omitted, a default value is used instead. Optional parameters are useful when the default value is used in most cases, but still needs to be specified on occasion.

To me, using Swift, optional means using `?` in reference to it perhaps being `nil`.

***EDIT***
Thanks for the response. It's evident that I should use default parameters. However, doing so in a `closure` result in the following error:

> "Default argument not permitted in a tuple type"

```
func characterIsMoving(i: Int, j: Int, completion: @escaping(_ moveWasWithinLimit: Bool, _ test: Bool = false ) -> Void) { ... }
```

Here comes the full function if that's helpful:

```
func characterIsMoving(i: Int, j: Int, completion: @escaping(_ moveWasWithinLimit: Bool, _ test: Bool = false ) -> Void) {
    if !gameBoardArray[i][j].isAccessibilityElement {
        print("Not Accessible")
        currentSelectedTile = character.getCurrentPosition()

        return
    }else {
        print("Moving")
        var moveWasWithinLimit: Bool

        if(characterMoveLimit.contains(currentSelectedTile)){
            print("Within Limit")
            previousSelectedTile.fillColor = SKColor.gray
            currentSelectedTile.fillColor = SKColor.brown
            placeCharacter(row: i, col: j)
            buttonIsAvailable = false

            for moveRadius in characterMoveLimit {
                moveRadius.fillColor = SKColor.gray
            }
            characterMoveLimit.removeAll()
            moveLimit(limitWho: "CHARACTER", characterOrEnemy: character, i: i, j: j)

            moveWasWithinLimit = true
            completion(moveWasWithinLimit)
        }else{
            print("Outside Move Limit")
            currentSelectedTile = previousSelectedTile
            moveWasWithinLimit = false
            completion(moveWasWithinLimit)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about [Default Parameter Values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID169) in the Swift book.

Comment: "Optional parameters" is a common term in other programming languages, but it's a bit confusing in Swift, because it could mean both a defaulted param (`func f(param: String = "default")`), or a parameter of an optional type (`func f(param: String?)`). Some functions can have both (`func f(param: String? = nil)`). In Swift, "defaulted parameter" is a more clear name, which unambiguously refers to the first case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (everyone, really) would *really* benefit from reading [the Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html), cover to cover.

What you're looking for is called a default value.

```
func test(paramA: String = "Your default value here") {}
```

or

```
func test(paramA: String? = nil) {}
```

The former is simpler, but more limited. For example, you can't distinguish rather the default value `"Your default value here"` was used, or whether the caller passed in their own value, which happens to be `"Your default value here"`). In my experience, the distinction is seldom required, but it's good to call out just in case.

In the latter case, you have the flexibility to handle the optional in many more ways. You could substitute a default value with `??`, do conditional binding, `map` it, etc.

Comment: thanks, but I'm trying to use the default parameter in a closure and get this error: `Default argument not permitted in a tuple type`...

Comment: @MarkTornej Closure types can't have defaulted parameters. The value of the default value of a defaulted parameter isn't part of the type of a closure.

Comment: I' mean I can get around the problem by adding a regular parameter, but that means that some `completion()` functions will take arguments that aren't used. That's fine, but not very elegant...

Comment: @MarkTornej I don't see any usages of the `test` parameter, so I can't prescribe a solution. But I suspect that what you're trying to do is model a call back that can have one of several different cases, each one with different data associated with it. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let's say the first completion should look like this `completion(argumentA)` and the second should look like this `completion(argumentB)`. But now both have to look like this `completion(argumentA, argumentB)` even though it only use one of the arguments. It works, but looks rather bad.

Comment: @MarkTornej Sounds like 1) you really need an enum, and 2) you *REALLY* need to watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S6UOrwS-Tg

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help @Alexander. I'll definitely check it out right away! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to be clear with your requirements.
2. You should not use methods which are directly dependent  on instance variables, as setting there values will be a problem according to your unit test cases.

As per my understanding this is the correct approach you can define the method with parameter having default value.
So that you can call that method as per your requirements  with or without the parameter.